# Which (Official) Arduino IDE to use?

Tags: arduino-ide, ide

I have bought an Arduino UNO that turned out to be the Italian version (Arduino SRL) not the American one (Arduino LLC).

Now when I go to arduino.org and arduino.cc, they both have different versions of the IDE!

So, which one should I use (if they are even different) ?

Comment: Neither. Use UECIDE ;)

Comment: Seriously though, the real answer is "It depends which side of the argument between the two Arduino parties you are on". Personally I am on the side of the .CC camp, so I would recommend to use the .CC version. Someone on the side of .ORG would recommend the .ORG version to use.

Comment: Possibly unnecessary warning: if you are expecting to have a coding experience similar to other IDEs, you might be surprised that there are "magic" includes rules and what would normally work in a typical GNU-like project might not work. This is meant to simplify the life to beginners, but not everyone likes it. The alternative is to use a plain Makefile and your favorite means to deal with Makefile - based projects.

Comment: .CC are open and welcoming. .ORG are sneaky and underhanded. For instance they create the same IDE but with a higher version number, so it appears newer than the .CC version. They also include (or have attempted to include) code to stop you being able to use non-.ORG boards.

Comment: Personally I would use the Arduino.CC version. However I'm going to close this question as being primarily opinion-based. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both IDEs no matter of the origin of the UNO even fake ones runs with the IDEs.
The arduino.org IDE is just a fork of the arduino.cc.
But arduino.org has many Board which are only run with the .org IDE.